# Detecting licence plates on cars with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I learning openCV lib in Python. I want to extract only licence plate/s from this image:
[image]

I applied a couple of processing, but I do not know how to select only licence plates. I have tried with haarcascades but It does not work.

```
This is the code that I have:
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread("slika3.jpg", 1)
#cv2.imshow('original', img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# covert image to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# apply bilateralFilter for smoothing the image
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 15, 17, 17)
cv2.imshow('blured gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# processing image to blackhat
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)
cv2.imshow('blackhat', blackhat)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#What next?
```

This is the final image. You will see that number and letters on plates are very clear, but I do not know how to select/extract them:

[image]

Comment: I did this project long ago..it's not really generic but works for a lot of cases. May be it can be of some help to you https://github.com/abhiabhi94/ANPR

Comment: I think you need to now capture images from the output that you have. Look out for `canny edge detector`.

Comment: There a lot of projects on github on this topic: https://github.com/topics/license-plate-recognition

Comment: Or you could read this article about OCV with Python + OpenCV: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/